# How can I make text in JQuery Datatable cell two different colours?

Tags: javascript, datatables

How can I make text in Datatable cell different colours simultaneously like the pink and blue here [image]

Here's the code:

```js
                    {
                        data: null,
                        render: function(data, type, row) {
                            return row.backOdds.toFixed(2) + "<BR>" +  row.exchangeType.layOdds.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: Provide a working example (jsfiddle.net will be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number you want to be different colors our the same numbers that are being rendered under your code snippet then you can do the following.

```js
                    {
                        data: null,
                        render: function(data, type, row) {
                            return "<span style='color:#00FF00'>" + row.backOdds.toFixed(2) + "</span><BR><span sytle='color:#FF0000'>" +  row.exchangeType.layOdds.toFixed(2) + '</span>;
                        }
                    },
```